# SPED - Bloco K - Registro 0220

Tags: erp, api

### Situação

Estou desenvolvendo o **Bloco K**(valido a partir de 2016) do [SPED EFD](http://www1.receita.fazenda.gov.br/sistemas/sped-fiscal/download/GUIA_PRATICO_DA_EFD-Versao_2.0.17.pdf), e estou com problemas para validar aparte de conversão de unidade.

### Estrutura teste

```
|0190|CX|CX.|
|0190|UN|UN.|
|0190|PC|PC.|
|0200|10001|ITEM 1|||CX|00|87089990||||17,00|
|0200|10002|ITEM 2|7899749104130||UN|00|87085099||||17,00|
|0200|10003|ITEM 3|||PC|00|84822010||84||17,00|
|0200|10004|ITEM 4|7892063009129||PC|00|84835090||||17,00|
|0220|CX|10|
...
|K100|01112016|30112016|
|K200|30112016|10001|10|0||
|K200|30112016|10002|3|0||
|K220|03112016|10001|10002|10|
|K220|03112016|10003|10004|1|
```

### Analise

#### Bloco

0190 = Unidade usadas
0200 = Identificação dos itens presentes no documento
0220 = Necessário quando ha conversão de unidade

K100 = Período de Apuração do inventario
K200 = Total no estoque ao final do mês
K220 = Conversões de item

#### Operação

Como podem ver eu estou realizando duas conversões :
10001 => 10002  - conversão para unidades diferente, necessário 0220.
10003 => 10004  - conversão para a mesma unidade, isento do 0220.

### Pratica

No sistema eu estou convertendo a CX(caixa) para a UN(unidade), ou seja estou abrindo a caixa para venda separada.

1(CX) => 10(UN)

### Testes

1. `|0220|CX|10|`
2. `|0220|UN|10|`
3. `|0220|CX|0,1|`
4. `|0220|UN|0,1|`

Todos geraram o mesmo erro.

### [Relatorio SPED](http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/declaracoes-e-demonstrativos/sped-sistema-publico-de-escrituracao-digital/escrituracao-fiscal-digital-efd/escrituracao-fiscal-digital-efd)

> O registro 0220 é obrigatório quando cod_item do 0200 tenha sido utilizado no campo COD_ITEM_DEST do k220 e este tiver unidade de medida diferente do código informado em COD_ITEM_ORI.

### Duvida

Alguém sabe como proceder para validar a conversão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chefe tem que ficar assim

```
|0190|CX|CX.|
|0190|UN|UN.|
|0190|PC|PC.|
|0200|10001|ITEM 1|||CX|00|87089990||||17,00|
|0200|10002|ITEM 2|7899749104130||UN|00|87085099||||17,00|
|0220|CX|5|
|0200|10003|ITEM 3|||PC|00|84822010||84||17,00|
|0200|10004|ITEM 4|7892063009129||PC|00|84835090||||17,00|
|0220|CX|10|
...
|K100|01112016|30112016|
|K200|30112016|10001|10|0||
|K200|30112016|10002|3|0||
|K220|03112016|10001|10002|10|
|K220|03112016|10003|10004|1|
```

Veja no K220 que você tenta efetuar uma transação interna mas o PVA não sabe de quantos para quantos.
Pois as unidades entre as transações são distintas entre os produtos.

Ex. 
Produto 10001 esta cadastrado como CX, o produto 10002 esta cadastrado como UN, ai você tenta efetuar uma transferência entre esses produtos e o sistema não vai saber quantas unidades de fato foi alterada, logo você precisa colocar a conversão do 10002 para a unidade do 10001 no caso de UN -> CX.

Comment: Realizei os teste, como você recomendou e realmente o arquivo foi validado, pelo que analisei a unidade de conversão `|0220|` deve ficar abaixo do código do item que foi convertido, poderia confirmar, por favor?

Comment: Sim, veja com relação ao nivel Hierarquico do registro 0220, ele sempre deve ficar abaixo do seu registro pai.
Resumindo seu problema não era os valores de conversão e sim em como estava montando sua estrutura.

Comment: Certo , obrigado o retorno :D